# Dockerfile COPY skipping over git submodules

Tags: docker, dockerfile, git-submodules

Is there some way to have a `Dockerfile`'s [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) command skip over Git submodules?

I know I can set up a `.dockerignore`, but I am wondering if it's possible to skip Git submodules without a `.dockerignore`.

Comment: You can list all other files.

Comment: Tools that aren't Git don't really know about Git submodules.  If Docker sees a directory it will by default include it in the build context, with no knowledge of what source-control repository it might be connected to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider for that a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/):

- In the first stage, you could [clone the necessary parts of your repository *without* the submodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---recurse-submodulesltpathspecgt) into a temporary directory.
- In the second stage, you can then copy over the cloned data from the first stage to the desired directory, thereby skipping over any Git submodules.

```
# First Stage: Clone repository without submodules
FROM alpine AS clone-stage
RUN apk add --no-cache git \
    && git clone --recurse-submodules=no https://github.com/your-repo.git /temp-dir

# Second Stage: Copy the cloned data
FROM your-base-image
COPY --from=clone-stage /temp-dir /your-destination-dir
```

No submodules in the final image.